# How to cast a type in Postgres/Postgis (and using sequelizejs)

Tags: postgresql, casting, sequelize.js

I have vector-tiles in postgis. No experience with casting types. The vector-tile-spec supports following types: string, float, double, int64, uint64, sint64, bool. This means that all PostgreSQL types other than Varchar, Text, CharArray, Float4, Float8, Int2, Int4, Int8, Bool have to be converted to one of these.

I have two fields in my table which are DATES i.e. 'timestamp with time zone': createdAt and updatedAt. I would like to store in a type that is supported, so how do I do this?

I currently:

1. make a schema with sequelize (which a.o. defines the DATE types)
2. a bulk import with ogr2ogr (in which Postgis creates defaultvalues
   for the DATES)
3. and after that CRUD with sequelize.

But all 3 (or at least 2 and 3) need to end up as a supported type.

- Into which type can I best cast my DATES?
- How do I do that (using sequelize hooks? using Postgres?)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd cast your dates to either an `INTEGER` or a `BIGINT`, depending on the date ranges you need to use, and just count days of [**Unix Time**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Assuming you just cast to `INTEGER`, you can define the following function to convert from `dates` to the number of days from the *epoch date* (`1970-01-01 00:00:00`):

```
CREATE FUNCTION days_from_reference_date(d date)
RETURNS INTEGER
AS
$$
    SELECT
        CAST(EXTRACT(epoch from d) / (60 * 60 * 24 /* seconds in a day */) AS INTEGER) ;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
STRICT
IMMUTABLE ;
```

You can use it in a scenario like this one:

```
SELECT
    days_from_reference_date(d) AS transformed_date
FROM
    dates
ORDER BY
    transformed_date ;
```

The back-conversion can be done with:

```
CREATE FUNCTION date_from_days_from_reference_date(days integer)
RETURNS date
AS
$$
    SELECT CAST(to_timestamp(cast(days as bigint) * 60 * 60 * 24) AS date);
$$
LANGUAGE SQL
STRICT
IMMUTABLE ;
```

You can check a few examples at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=6a3acd356aea127e10f00c2773b93c98)*

---

References:

- [Postgresql Date/Time Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). Look for `to_timestamp` and `extract(epoch from ...)`.

---

**Caveat**: offsets by one day with dates BC; if you ever need them. It can probably be solved by checking for them in the back-conversion function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is very helpful. Could you maybe also suggest on how to implement it as the required behavior would be to have a timestamp created which then instantly is cast into a number (or text).

Comment: If you need to handle `timestamps` instead of `dates`, use the previous functions without dividing or multiplying by (24 * 60 * 60). As for the implementation details: it depends a lot of which ETL tools you're using. I would probably stage the data in some temporary PostgreSQL tables, create some views out from them that convert your `timestamps` to `integer` or `bigint` and export those to your final system. I don't know how `sequelize.js` works, so, I can't go any further than a general approach.